# Is there a way to make alt+space work in chrome under ubuntu?

Tags: google-chrome, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm a keyboard junkie and there's some irony here somewhere that chrome running under ubuntu is the only application I've ever found that won't open the window menu when you hit alt-space.
I know they're google and they need to have their own superior interface, but I can't alt+space-n to minimize the window like I can for EVERY OTHER APPLICATION EVER WRITTEN.

Anybody know of a workaround?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a global "Ubuntu" issue, depends on what windows manager / desktop environmment you're using, perhaps even version issues.

I'm on 12.04 Ubuntu using Gala / mutter and my (current stable) Chrome doesn't show this problem.

Note the keybinding for the 'window menu' is set in Dconf's org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings, but many wm/de 's have other locations where their (sometimes different overlapping) bindings can be customized.

Comment: I'll check it out, it just seems odd that every other program works except chrome, leads me to believe it's a chrome problem, not anything else.